How to maintain sequence order in nested lists when using AutoMapper in C#
I have a c# object Design which has DesignSection child objects  and each design section has a sequence number along with other properties. I am using automapper to map between objects and dtos.
Problem is when I map from dto to object or back the sequence number gets mixed between both DesignSection lists. e-g
DesignDto
DesignSectionDto1 -> Sequence -> 1
DesignSectionDto2 -> Sequence -> 2
DesignSectionDto3 -> Sequence -> 3

After mapping is done, it becomes:
Design
DesignSection1 -> Sequence -> 2
DesignSection2 -> Sequence -> 3
DesignSection3 -> Sequence -> 1

I have created the maps correctly probably a small thing thats missing to retain the order of Sequence.
Any help would be appreciated.

Without seeing your mapping config its guesswork. A more common note you shouldn't really on ordering of things in List in your models. There are to many options where things can fail when mapping,serializing,storing etc. If you need a certain order have a fitting property in your model classes to explicitly sort by. Don'T really on List class indexes.

I found solution to this after messing with it for quite some time.
Before, my mapping config looked something like this:
CreateMap<DesignDto, Design>();

Now i added order by statement for each member and it was able retain the original order and map the correct sequence numbers to the corresponding design sections.
CreateMap<DesignDto, Design>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.DesignSections, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DesignSections.OrderBy(cid => cid.Sequence)));


